# Discord.py tempmute command work even after reboot

Tags: discord.py

I've got this code for my discord bot to temporarily mute people:

```
@bot.command()
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, d, *, reason=None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
    if not mutedRole:
        mutedRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")

    for channel in guild.channels:
        await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True)
    for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == "Muted":
            await member.add_roles(role)

            embed = discord.Embed(title="TempMuted!", description=f"{member.mention} has been tempmuted.", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
            embed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=reason, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="Time for the mute:", value=f"{time}{d}", inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

            if d == "s":
                await asyncio.sleep(time)

            if d == "m":
                await asyncio.sleep(time*60)

            if d == "h":
                await asyncio.sleep(time*60*60)

            if d == "d":
                await asyncio.sleep(time*60*60*24)

            await member.remove_roles(role)

            embed = discord.Embed(title="Unmute (temp mute expired) ", description=f"Unmuted -{member.mention} ", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

            return
```

However, my bot reboots itself every 12-24 hours, and if someone is currently temp muted while the bot reboots, they never get unmuted, as the bot forgets that it ever muted them, so they remain muted until I manually unmute them. Is there a way so I can make it so the bot still remembers to unmute them, even if the bot reboots during their mute period? If so, please could you show me what I should add in my code to do so. Thank you!

Note: in case it helps, I host my bot via GitHub and Heroku, in case that helps with anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a text file, but it won't be much accurate:

```
@bot.command()
async def tempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, d, *, reason=None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
    if not mutedRole:
        mutedRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted")

    for channel in guild.channels:
        await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, speak=False, send_messages=False, read_message_history=True)

    await member.add_roles(mutedRole)

    embed = discord.Embed(title="TempMuted!", description=f"{member.mention} has been tempmuted.", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
    embed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=reason, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Time for the mute:", value=f"{time}{d}", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    if d == "s":
        mutetime = time

    if d == "m":
        mutetime = time*60

    if d == "h":
        mutetime = time*60*60

    if d == "d":
        mutetime = time*60*60*24

    with open("TXT_FILE_PATH", "w+") as mutetimef:
        mutetime.write(mutetime)
    
    while True:
        with open("TXT_FILE_PATH", "w+") as mutetimef:
            if int(mutetimef.read()) == 0:
                await member.remove_roles(mutedRole)

                embed = discord.Embed(title="Unmute (temp mute expired) ", description=f"Unmuted -{member.mention} ", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  
                return
            else:
                mutetime -= 1
                mutetimef.seek(0)
                mutetimef.truncate()
                mutetimef.write(mutetime)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

You also need to create a .txt file which this is being saved in. As I said this won't be too accurate but it works. Also you have to define variable or something which looks after the restart if this is running and if not it runs it